# How do I fix eclipse's hang on 66% while building workspace?

Tags: linux, java, eclipse

I am using Linux Mint Debian

Eclipse 3.5.2

Anytime I save it gets stuck on 66%

Need to know how to diagnose or fix the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your workspace log for errors:

```
less workspace/.metadata/.log
```

Or tail while saving:

```
tail -f workspace/.metadata/.log
```

Comment: This was a great idea, though no new logs came up while saving

Comment: try starting eclipse from the command line and see if it outputs any errors to the terminal

Comment: No errors were reported and I tried using `-clean` command, but did not help

Comment: Removed build automatically fixed the issue.

Comment: problem was the time it took to build a large shared library

Answer (score 0):

One way is to rename `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml` to `workbench.xml.bak`.  This  basically wipes the workbench state.  After starting eclipse it seems to have stopped from this condition of hanging on cleaning/building the workspace.